# No benefit of using AsParallel in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing

Here is my sample project:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time in milliseconds:");

        swSingle.Start();
        var numbers2 = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000000);
        var singleResult = numbers2
            .Where(i => i % 2 == 0)
            .ToArray();
        swSingle.Stop();      
        Console.WriteLine("Without AsParallel: {0}", swSingle.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        swParallel.Start();
        var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000000);
        var parallelResult = numbers.AsParallel()
            .Where(i => i % 2 == 0)
            .ToArray();
        swParallel.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Using AsParallel: {0}", swParallel.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

The output on my (multi-core)system is:

```
Elapsed time in milliseconds:
Without AsParallel: 1537
Using AsParallel: 2135
```

Why don´t I get a time advantage in this sample
by using AsParallel? Even worse there seems to 
be much overhead.

Comment: The calculation of `i % 2` is a too simple use case for parallelization. This takes more efford to manage task parallelization then calculating your result.

Comment: More correctly, `.AsParallel` is not magic dust that makes everything faster. It has a costs. You should only use it then the benefit outweighs the cost. More accurately, there is a small overhead for each parallelization, WHICH in your case, is MUCH BIGGER than the calculation itself.

Comment: You might want to check out partitioners.  _"[In general, range partitioning is only faster when the execution time of the delegate is small to moderate, and the source has a large number of elements, and the total work of each partition is roughly equivalent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411.aspx)"_.  Even so, your example is very elementary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply takes more time to make your code run in parallel (create a task, schedule and run it) than the advantage you gain by executing that code in parallel.

That said, this makes very clear not every piece of code benefits of running in parallel. You can only use it on substantial code segment with a high CPU load or external I/O (like a HTTP request).

Answer (score 1):

Modulo operation takes O(1) time as it is considered to be a simple action. Using Linq, you get O(n) complexity (you actually loop through everything) which is still not that complex.

And when you run your func with `.AsParallel` you simply add more overhead to your actions.

Try working with more complex functions and/or tasks that actually requires multiple CPU cores so that you might see a noticeable difference.